# How can I read image info on the command line?

Tags: command-line, metadata

Is there a command that can read image attributes? I only need to get the height or width.

Comment: do you want metadata extraction

Comment: @George. While the slash is usually used to indicate *or*, I'm pretty confident that in this context it meant *and*.

Comment: @TRiG, I usually don't fancy trying to guess what the OP is saying or trying to especially when OP did write some thing down. But perhaps your right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `file`

Or the more advanced command `identify` from the ImageMagick package.

Comment: Good one , I never thought file can extract those info as well

Comment: @warl0ck I'd still use identify though, as it's much easier to get the data you want. `read -r width height < <(identify -format "%w %h" "$imagefile")`

Answer (score 1):

The `file` command works fine for some formats like PNG. But I guess it will not work for JPEGs.

For JPEGs you can use one of the following commands.

```
convert image.jpg -print "Size: %wx%h\n" /dev/null

identify -format "%wx%h" photo.jpg
```

Both of them require `imagemagick`, which may already be installed. You can install it by running

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```